# Store 2 dimensional array from a SQL query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays

```
$query = "select id, name, email from users";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error());
$users = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_BOTH);
```

I did research on google, however, I didn't find a good answer.

I am trying to store results from a SQL query in an 2 dimentional array that will contain all the users and then to use the array.

mysql_fetch_array returns only 1 row and it's not helping me..

In the attached image (table), for `$users[1][name]`  I want to receive "Bar" (assuming that the indicator starting in 0 and I want the second row).

Example Table:

[image]

UPDATE:

```
$query = "select Traveler_Username,Traveler_First_Name from users";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error());
echo '<table align="center" border="1" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5" style="border-collapse: collapse; background-color: #FF66AE66"><tr align="center"><td><b>Username</b></td><td><b>First Name</b></td><td></tr>';
        while($first = mysql_fetch_array($result)){ 
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>".$first["Traveler_Username"]."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$first["Traveler_First_Name"]."</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        } // end While
```

This code make an output of the attached image. However, I still don't know how to use the content inside the array (like to store a name in another variable)..

[image: Example Image 1]

Comment: `while ($users = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_BOTH)) {
 ...
}`

Comment: echo $users[1][name] will be "Bar" (second row, second Column)?

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not learn the obsolete [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface. It's awful and has been removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) helps explain best practices. Make **sure** your user parameters are [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) or you will end up with severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: You certainly need to clarify this statement: "I still don't know how to use the content inside the array (like to store a name in another variable).."

Comment: I do a SQL query, for example the result is 3 columns and 5 rows. I want to obtain the data in a array and to be able to extract value from the array. Such as in row 2, column 3 the value is "computer". I want to be able to a command like $answer = $array[1][2] and the variable "$answer" will contain the value "computer. Is it clear now? The syntax is what I need

Comment: which name to store??? and what you do with that array?

Comment: I want to obtain the value that in the second row and the third column of the 2 dimensional array to another variable, such as $answer...

Answer (score 1):

Create an array and put the result to this array.

```
$new_arr = array();

$query = "select id, name, email from users";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error());

while($users = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_BOTH)){
    $new_arr[] = $users;
}

print_r($new_arr); //this is a two dimensional array
```

Comment: echo  $new_arr[1][name] will be "Bar" (second row, second Column)?

Comment: @YuvalAsher, did you done?? I mean are you benefited?? if not then let me know.

Comment: I still not succeed to use the content in the array. I am updating my question - look there please

Comment: What you want?? Did you want to get a specific value? or want to design a two dimensional array???

Comment: your question `Store 2 dimensional array from a SQL query` is done with `print_r($new_arr);`.

Comment: I want you get able to use the 2 dimensional array. Like array[i][j].. tnx

Comment: I do a SQL query, for example the result is 3 columns and 5 rows. I want to obtain the data in a array and to be able to extract value from the array. Such as in row 2, column 3 the value is "computer". I want to be able to a command like $answer = $array[1][2] and the variable "$answer" will contain the value "computer. Is it clear now? The syntax is what I need

Comment: Wait... I was in road, returning from office.